# Proof for self-conjugate

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Prove that there are no self-conjugate partitions of n, whose third part is 2, when n is an odd integer.

My attempt: let n = 5, (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1), (3 + 2), (3 + 1 + 1), (2+ 2 + 1), (4 + 1), (2 + 1 + 1 + 1). I see that the third part is odd (or 1), but how do I go about proving this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Ferrers diagram of a self-conjugate partition with third part 2 to show that $n=8+2k$ for some nonnegative integer $k$.  You must have at least these 8:
$$\begin{matrix}
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \dots \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \dots \\
\bullet & \bullet & \circ & \circ \\
\dots & \dots & \circ & \circ
\end{matrix}$$
And any additional ones appear in pairs because of self-conjugacy.

Comment: I think I get the gist of it. Since the third row has 2, then that means that row two >= 2. For each additional boxes in row two > 2, add one below row three column two. Not sure if this is correct